# progressive word combination of a string

Tags: php, algorithm, string, factorial

I need to obtain a progressive word combination of a string.

E.g. "this is string"
Output: "this is string"
        "this is"
        "this string"
        "is string"
        "this"
        "is"
        "string"

Do you know similar algorithm? (I need it in php language)
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple code solution to your problem.
I concatenate each string recoursively to the remaining ones in the array.

```
$string = "this is a string";  
$strings = explode(' ', $string);

// print result
print_r(concat($strings, ""));

// delivers result as array
function concat(array $array, $base_string) {

    $results = array();
    $count = count($array);
    $b = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $elem){
        $new_string = $base_string . " " . $elem;
        $results[] = $new_string;
        $new_array = $array;

        unset($new_array[$key]);

        $results = array_merge($results, concat ($new_array, $new_string));

    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 1):

Check out eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Systematic_generation_of_all_permutations for an algorithm description.

Comment: Thank for your answear. I need to change progressively to the number of words and not just the simple permutation. Eg. ("1 2 3") output ("123","12","13","23","1","2","3")

Comment: Then just combine the algorithm with another that produces all of the combinations! :)

Comment: this is my question :D. I don't know the algorithm that produces all of the combinations :D